# Add custom text to Dropdown list for MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a dropdown I want to add to my _Layout.cshtml page in MVC 5.  This is returned from Reference data in my Database - it is for CarTypes.  There are 4 different types of car model that can be selected - Saloon, 4X4, Estate and Hatchback.

I created a CarTypesViewModel as below:

```
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CarTypesList { get; set; }

 public string SelectedCarType { get; set; }
```

I then have a view :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    //Just a html div here perhaps?
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCarType, Model.CarTypesList)
}
```

Within the layout i have the following:

```
<li id="selectedcar">@Html.Action("Index", "CarTypes")</li>
```

This then goes to this action in my CarTypes controller:

```
  var model = new CarTypesViewModel 
        {
            CarTypesList= products.Select(p => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = p.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                Text = p.Name
            })
        };

        return View(model);
```

This is returning the data to the Dropdown list.  However what I really want is for a Value to appear like Please Select Your Car Type as the first item in the list - what is the best way to achieve that as I dont want to store that as a value in my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCarType, 
    new SelectList(Model.CarTypesList, "Value", "Text"), 
    "--- Please Select Your Car Type ---", 
    new { @class = "form-control" }
)
```

Comment: Cheers - missed that in the overrides for DropDownListFor :)

Comment: The only other thing not might be the niceset with the approach I have taken is that a user could navigate directly to the CarTypes view by entering that url in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in the `optionLabel` argument to `DropDownListFor`.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703561(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    //Just a html div here perhaps?
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCarType, Model.CarTypesList, "Please Select Your Car Type")
}
```

This should do it.. (Adding your custom text as 3th element.)