# How to display 2 fields from the same table in the drop-down list MVC C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm beginner in c#, and I have problem.
I have a "Person" table, (id, first name, last name). I want to create a new person, but I only have the name in the drop-down list. I need to display the name and last name.

My controller:

```
// GET: Magazyn
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var magazyn = db.Magazyn.Include(m => m.Tools).Include(m => m.Person);
        return View(magazyn.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Magazyn/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Magazyn magazyn = db.Magazyn.Find(id);
        if (magazyn == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(magazyn);
    }

    // GET: Magazyn/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        ViewBag.IdOsoby = new SelectList(db.Person, "Id", "Name",  "Last Name");
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdPerson, "IdPerson", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("IdPerson", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdPerson, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782671/add-custom-text-to-dropdown-list-for-mvc-5

Comment: Thank you, but I do not know how to use in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   var selectList = db.Person.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = $"{x.Firstname} - {x.Lastname}", Value = x.Id.ToString()});
   ViewBag.IdOsoby = new SelectList(selectList, "Value", "Text");

   return View();
}
```

The error happens because we're trying to format the string of first name and surname. There's a couple of ways to do this. Firstly go ahead and make another `Person` class, make sure to mark it `partial` and ensure it is in the same namespace as your `Person` entity. So something like:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public string FullName => $"{Firstname} {Lastname}";
}
```

As you can see I have introduced a readonly property of fullname which is a combination of First and Last name. Now you can change your code in the `Create` action as:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   ViewBag.IdOsoby = new SelectList(db.Person.ToList(), "Id", "FullName");

   return View();
}
```

Comment: The drop-down list still does not work.  I make some simple, incomprehensible mistakes.  I posted my code above.

Comment: @Kris Change `@Html.DropDownList("IdPerson", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })` to `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdPerson, (SelectList)ViewBag.IdOsoby, new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: I receive this message: "[NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.]"

Comment: Izzy thank you very, very much. Everything works as it should. You are very helpful. Thanks to you the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I make some simple, incomprehensible mistakes. My code currently looks like this. The drop-down list still does not work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Legoland.Models;

namespace Legoland.Controllers
{
    public class MagazynController : Controller
    {
        private LegolandEntities db = new LegolandEntities();

        // GET: Magazyn
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var magazyn = db.Magazyn.Include(m => m.xxx).Include(m => m.Person);
            return View(magazyn.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Magazyn/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Magazyn magazyn = db.Magazyn.Find(id);
            if (magazyn == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(magazyn);
        }

        // GET: Magazyn/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.Idxxx = new SelectList(db.xxx, "Id", "xxx");
            ViewBag.IdPerson = new SelectList(db.Person, "Id", "Name", "LastName");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Magazyn/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,IdPerson,Idxxx,yyy,zzzz")] Magazyn magazyn)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Magazyn.Add(magazyn);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.Idxxx = new SelectList(db.xxx, "Id", "xxx", magazyn.Idxxx);
            ViewBag.IdPerson = new SelectList(db.Person, "Id", "Name", "LastName", magazyn.Person);
            return View(magazyn);
        }

        // GET: Magazyn/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Magazyn magazyn = db.Magazyn.Find(id);
            if (magazyn == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.Idxxx = new SelectList(db.xxx, "Id", "xxx", magazyn.Idxxx);
            var selectList = db.Person.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = $"{x.Name} - {x.LastName}", Value = x.Id.ToString() });
            ViewBag.IdPerson = new SelectList(selectList, "Value", "Text");
            return View(magazyn);
        }

        // POST: Magazyn/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,IdPerson,Idxxx,yyy,zzz")] Magazyn magazyn)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(magazyn).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.Idxxx = new SelectList(db.xxx, "Id", "yyy", magazyn.Idxxx);
            var selectList = db.Person.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = $"{x.Name} - {x.LastName}", Value = x.Id.ToString() });
            ViewBag.IdPerson = new SelectList(selectList, "Value", "Text");
            return View(magazyn);
        }

        // GET: Magazyn/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Magazyn magazyn = db.Magazyn.Find(id);
            if (magazyn == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(magazyn);
        }

        // POST: Magazyn/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Magazyn magazyn = db.Magazyn.Find(id);
            db.Magazyn.Remove(magazyn);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

And View Create.cs:

```
@model Legoland.Models.Magazyn

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Magazyn</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Person, "IdPerson", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("IdPerson", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdPerson, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>

            }

            <div>
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
            </div>
```